# jQuery UI functions are undefined inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scope

I have jQuery UI's datepicker function running on one of my pages. Stripping it way down, it works like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#date").datepicker();
</script>
```

Since this part works, I know the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts are included correctly, etc.

Now, I want to activate the date picker from inside one of my functions, like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
</form>
<a href="JavaScript:test();">test</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        alert(jQuery("#date")); // this works as expected
        jQuery("#date").datepicker(); // this throws an error
    }
</script>
```

But when the datepicker function runs inside my function, JavaScript throws the error *TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery("#date").datepicker()')*. It looks like the datepicker function is not available within the scope of my function, even though the jQuery("#date") object is available.

Does anyone have an explanation or a workaround for this?

UPDATE: After ragnarok56 posted the jsfiddle demonstrating the code working, I went back to my page to look more carefully at what might be affecting it. This is part of a larger system that administrators can customize by adding their own header and footer code, and it turns out that an administrator had added his own link to an older jQuery script in the footer. I removed that and my code worked as expected. I also replaced my jQuery include with his and my code still worked, so it seems the problem is not the old version of jQuery, but including jQuery twice. It seems strange that this would prevent the jQuery function from working inside a function but not outside a function, so I'll leave this open in case someone can provide an explanation of that behavior.

Comment: Try  `console.log(jQuery("#date"))` instead and check whether `datepicker` is defined on that object (should be a property of `jQuery.fn`)

Comment: most likely a scope issue?

Comment: couldnt configure the code the exact way in jsfiddle, but this jsbin seems to work fine in chrome.  browser issue? http://jsbin.com/otequx/1/edit

Comment: Based on your code above, this should work. A jQuery object's properties shouldn't vary with scope - are these two different pages? Note that your alert() line will still print [object Object] even if the #date element isn't found. Maybe walk through the debugger and make sure the element is found?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy You're right, that's not a good test ... I just saw that alerting jQuery("#datex") gives the same result. Oops. I'll do more work on that.

Comment: @ragnarok56, thanks for that. Your jsfiddle works for me in the same browsers where my own page doesn't work. I'm going through now looking for a difference that I missed.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I just changed alert(jQuery("#date")) to jQuery("#date").css("background-color", "red"); and that worked fine. So it does seem that the problem is specific to jQuery UI functions and not jQuery built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update, the problem is that jQuery was included after jQuery UI.

When jQuery UI initializes, it essentially builds itself into the existing jQuery code. If you include another version of jQuery after that, the original jQuery (with jQuery UI attached!) will be thrown out. Which is why UI-specific methods like datepicker are throwing errors.

Definitely better to only include jQuery once, but including jQuery UI *again* after the second jQuery instance would (probably) work correctly.

EDIT: The reason it works outside a function is, very likely, that it ran there before the second copy of jQuery had overwritten the first. The function runs later, perhaps?

Comment: That totally makes sense. And your explanation of why it worked outside of the function is also correct. I thought it was a scoping issue, but that was a red herring. I think I will move my own jQuery links to the end of the page and include them conditionally if they don't already exist, to address the problem of administrators adding their own copies.